# Why cant I add a trendline with ggplots?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics

I am teaching myself R and I want to predict the exponential growth for 2023, 2024 and 2025. My data is (data.growth) :

```
   Year Articles
1  2005   1.0000
2  2006   3.0000
3  2007   2.0000
4  2008   3.0000
5  2009   9.0000
6  2010  14.0000
7  2011  16.0000
8  2012  18.0000
9  2013  32.0000
10 2014  40.0000
11 2015  49.0000
12 2016  34.0000
13 2017  50.0000
14 2018  42.0000
15 2019  60.0000
16 2020  59.0000
17 2021  94.0000
18 2022  76.0000
```

I use the following code:

```
model1 <- lm(log(Articles) ~ Year, data = data.growth)
summary (model1)

new_data <- data.frame(Year = c(2023, 2024, 2025))
predicted_values.exp <- exp(predict(model1, newdata = new_data))
predictions <- data.frame(Year = c(2023, 2024, 2025), Articles = predicted_values.exp)
predictions
data.growth.exp <- rbind(data.growth, predictions)
```

with this i obtained the predicted values for 2023, 2024 and 2025. I tried to plot it with an exponential trendline.

I used the following:

```
point.data <- seq(2005, 2025, 0.1)
point.values <- exp(predict(model1, list (Year = point.data)))
plot(data.growth.exp)
lines(point.data, point.values, lwd=2, col = "red", xlab = "Time (s)", ylab = "Counts")
```

with this graph:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiKJf.png)

I obtained exactly what i want but im trying to get the same using `ggplot()`. I tried the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.growth.exp, aes(Year, Articles)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "nls" , formula = y ~ a * exp(b * x), se = FALSE, method.args = list(start = list(a = 1, b = 1)))
```

but i get the following:

Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model

I already tried to modify everything i could but i dont really get what i am doing wrong. As i said, im teaching myself and my only guide is tutorials and people that tried a similar thing as me. I tried to understand it but i dont get why is so difficult using ggplot.

Answer (score 0):

maybe I am misunderstanding the math behind this. but why is it `y ~ a * exp(b * x)` instead of `y ~ exp(a + b * x)`?

considering that `model1` is `log(y) ~ a + b * x` so in `nls()` it should be `y ~ exp(a + b * x)`

Doing `geom_smooth(method = "nls" , formula = y ~ exp(a+b * x), se = FALSE, method.args = list(start = list(a = 1, b = 0)))` instead works.

[image]